# Url not working

Tags: c#, url, amazon-s3, urlencode

I am showing PDF files in browser and facing some issue with the urls.

```
2B%2bSewer%2cWater%2ctestdra-ghjguson-COB%2bReview+(6).pdf
```

The above link is working its from aws but when i am doing Url encoidng of below file name

```
2B+Sewer,Water,testdra-ghjguson-COB+Review+(6).pdf
```

the name becomes

```
2B%2bSewer%2cWater%2ctestdra-ghjguson-COB%2bReview%2b(6).pdf
```

which is not working.

Any one faced this issue before why this last + sign in the url need not to be encoded.

Comment: What is the actual file name?  This is likely ambiguity because `+` can also represent a whitespace.

Comment: 2B+Sewer,Water,testdra-ghjguson-COB+Review+(6).pdf

Comment: Are you saying the actual filename contains parenthesis, plus signs and commas?

Comment: Original file contains it . After uploading its name changed to 2B%2bSewer%2cWater%2ctestdra-ghjguson-COB%2bReview+(6).pdf  The last plus sign why it has not been encoded?